# create new album in company page

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use graph API to create new album in one of pages under my account.
It's the company page and I know the page ID.

What I have tried which fails:

```
query = string.Format("me/page?name={0},albums?name={1}", PageID, AlbumTitle);
```

And I have also tried which fails:

```
query = string.Format("{0}/albums?name={1}, PageID, AlbumTitle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [Graph API doc says](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/#album), you need to issue POST request to `PAGE_ID/albums`. Using C# facebook api you should do something like this:

```
private string GetOrCreateAlbumId(FacebookClient api, string profileId, string name, int albumNumber = 0)
{
    var fullName = albumNumber == 0 ? name : string.Format("{0}_{1}", name, albumNumber);

    dynamic d = api.Get(string.Format("{0}/albums", profileId), new { fields = "id,name,count", limit = "9999" });
    var data = (JsonArray)((JsonObject)d).Values.First();

    try
    {
        if (data == null || data.Any() == false || data.FirstOrDefault(x => ((JsonObject)x)["name"].ToString() == fullName) == null)
        {
            // no such album - create new one
            var param = new { name = fullName };
            var album = api.Post(string.Format("{0}/albums", profileId), param);

            return ((JsonObject)album)["id"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            var album = (JsonObject)data.First(x => ((JsonObject)x)["name"].ToString() == fullName);

            int imageCount = 0;
            if (album.ContainsKey("count"))
            {
                int.TryParse(album["count"].ToString(), out imageCount);
            }

            if (imageCount > 500)
            {
                albumNumber++;

                return this.GetOrCreateAlbumId(api, profileId, name, albumNumber);
            }

            return album["id"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var msg = string.Format("Data: {0}\r\nAlbum Name: {1}\r\nAlbum number: {2}", data, name, albumNumber);
        throw new Exception(msg, ex);
    }
}
```

this function does the following:

1. First, it checks if album named `name` already exists - and if it does:

   - check total number of images - and it's larger that maximum allowed - [which is 200 currently](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) - then create `name_1`, `name_2` etc albums.
   - if we still have room to upload photos - just return the album id
2. If there is no such album - create new one and return its id:

   ```
       var param = new { name = fullName };
       var album = api.Post(string.Format("{0}/albums", profileId), param);

       return ((JsonObject)album)["id"].ToString();
   ```

**EDIT**
Regarding `profileId` field - I use this function to call for various users who authorized my application. In your case that would be the pageId.

Comment: Can profileId be anything user want or should be received from facebook server?  How does facebook know that album is under company page and not the user who has the company page?

Comment: @JP_medevice I updated the answer. Regarding "how does the Facebook know" - it's all in the token you provide. If you don't have a valid token, then the call will fail.

Comment: Yeah that I know, and should the ProfileID be the company page ID? I am asking this because I have the company page under my user account and token is same for both. When I use company page ID as profile ID, I get OAuth error as before.

Comment: "token is same for both" - that means you are getting it wrong. It should be different - see my answer to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20175855/1246870